# Redirecting to force usage of www and SSL for domain in Plesk

Tags: ssl, url-rewriting, plesk

I have been using this in order to force usage of HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And this works perfectly fine.

How can I modify this rule so that it also forces a `www.` prefix for the domain **and** SSL? Perhaps it can be done right within the `RewriteRule` line above? That would be best. But I don't think it can be done, because of the condition applying only to non-HTTPS calls?

Unfortunately my knowledge of Apache configuration and its syntax goes way below zero.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain your downvote so i can either improve my question or adapt my approach. Commentless downvotes are constructively useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This is shorter actually.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank You, Jack. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. The forward from HTTP to HTTPS works fine, but the prefixing of the URL with *www* doesn't work. I am not sure why, but i am certain that i applied the configuration properly (and i called plesk *httpdmng* to reconfigure the domain).

Comment: I don't use plesk and most control panels _seem_ to change the way the original config works. However a standard rewrite should still work. I use that for my own site and you can test it here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ Is what you posted the entire contents of your htaccess?

Comment: I need to correct myself. It seems that this solution works, but the problem is that even BEFORE the connection is made, i get a warning when NOT applying the *www* to the domain, because the SSL certificate is only valid for the domain *including* the *www*. It dawns on me now that perhaps using rewrites it is impossible to solve this problem. However, the question has been properly answered as it was not about the certificate and domain-related issues, but only the rewrite. Thank You for your help!

Comment: Ok no problem. BTW Some CA's allow you to have an alternate such as www when purchasing your cert. So that you can use either www or non www for the same cert. All of mine do. If I want to use anything else then I purchase a wildcard cert. however you might be able to rekey depending on if they allow it or not.